# Remove a connection between two nodes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, raphael, draw2d-js

I'm trying to remove an existing connection(DragConnectionCreatePolicy) between two nodes. I tried two ways, the first using this command:

`this.canvas.remove(connection)` but it returns this: `EXCEPTION: figure.getCanvas is not a function`

The second one

```
var cmd =  new draw2d.CommandDelete(connection);
this.canvas.getCommandStack().execute(cmd)
```

instead returns `EXCEPTION: draw2d.CommandDelete is not a constructor`

What am I mistaking?

I'm using draw2d inside an Angular 2 component.

```
export class sampleDraw implements OnInit {


  canvas:any;

  createGraph() {

    this.canvas = new draw2d.Canvas("canvas-div");

}

ngOnInit(){
    this.createGraph()

  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed if I put like parameter an object figure.class the method this.canvas.remove(figure) works, if I put n object connection.class doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is code which you want in draw2d libray. I think you can remove the connection that already connected like this:

```
this.canvas.lines.remove(connection);
connection.setCanvas(null);
connection.disconnect();
```

> UPDATE:
>
> I found a way to remove any items in draw2d. Please define the command
>   to delete the item. And execute it.
>
> ```
> let cmd = connection.createCommand(new draw2d.command.CommandType(draw2d.command.CommandType.DELETE));
> if (cmd !== null) {                     
>     connection.getCanvas().getCommandStack().execute(cmd);
> }
> ```

Comment: The method doesn't work but there aren't errors in the console